# Can you please tell how to repeat and truncate an audio file using python?

Tags: python, audio

I need to pre-process some audio files such as :
1)if the audio file is shorter than 10 seconds repeat the file and concatenate it

2) if the audio file is longer tan 10 seconds then the audio was truncated.
I'm using python for this  and i tried this

```
length_s = len(data)/float(samplerate)
   if(length_s < 10.0):
        data1=10.0-length_s 
        data2=np.append(data,data1)
        #data2=np.append(data,data1*data)
    if(length_s > 10.0):
        data1=length_s-10.0
        data2=np.remove(data,data1)
    else:
        print('Audio file duration is 10 seconds')
```

in the above code `data2=np.append(data,data1)` no change to the audio file but for `data2=np.append(data,data1*data)`the data is appended with high sound and duration is not come to 10 seconds.and for truncation`data2=np.remove(data,data1)`  is not showing any change to the audio file.

Comment: Without seeing how you create `data` it is difficult to confirm if `length_s = len(data)/float(samplerate)` is actually correct. Also, the indentation of this is off so the second `if` statement should be inline with the first. That said, it should probably be `elif`. Also, it would be advisable to make comparisons based on length in samples rather than duration in seconds. The chances of `length_s` being equal to `10.0` is quite small. I would avoid floating point `==` comparison as well.

Comment: In some, start thinking about duration in samples

Comment: Just to narrow down your thinking. What is your expectation of the result of the line `data2=np.append(data,data1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response .Actually I'm a beginner and don't know much about python and audio processing.I understood about the indentation and elif but don't know how to compare the audios based on length in samples.

Comment: Expectation of the result of the line 'data2=np.append(data,data1)' is to repeat the audio file for balance duration.(If the original audio has length 4 seconds then it should repeat same audio for 6 seconds to make it 10 seconds)

Comment: If that is the case I would recommend walking through this line by line in a python console and inspecting each variable. Your `data` should be an array of sample values. `data1` is just going to be a bible value that you are appending onto `data` to create `data2`. Play with `np.append()` to see what actually does, not on the audio data but rather just on a small test array.

Comment: You have two separate problems here to deal with. _How to program with python_ and _how to process digital audio_. They are mutually exclusive, you will solve your problem a lot quicker by tackling the problems individually.

Comment: Your length in samples is simply `len(data)`, unless `data` is `byte data` in which case you would need to divide by the number of _bytes per sample_ (i.e. bit depth) to get the number of samples.

Comment: Thanks for the response....i will try this